# Prove that a set $Y$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ is open if and only if it contains none of its boundary points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I will preface this question by saying that I realise that there are a lot of *similar* questions to this one, which have already been answered on this site, but none, which are exactly this question.

> Question: Prove that a set $Y$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ is open if and only if it contains none of its boundary points.

I'm asking if my following proof is correct. I feel as if it's slightly not as rigorous as it could be, so any suggestions and pointers to improve would be greately appreciated.

**Proof:** Suppose for the forward implication, that the set $Y\subseteq (X,d)$ is open and contains at least one of the boundary points of $Y$. Since $Y$ is open, then for each $x\in Y$ there must exist an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq Y$. This is true for all such elements in $Y$; as such there must exist $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $B(g,\varepsilon_0)\subseteq Y$ where $g\in Y\cap \mathrm{Bd}(Y) \neq \emptyset$ (because we have assumed there is at least one element of the boundary in $Y$). However, since $g\in \mathrm{Bd}(Y)$, then every open-ball centred at $g$ must contain elements of both $Y$ and $Y^c$. This will certainly be true for the open-ball $B(g,\varepsilon_0)$, which contradicts the fact that $ B(g,\varepsilon_0)\subseteq Y$. Hence, $Y$ cannot contain any boundary points.

For the reverse implication, suppose that $Y \subseteq (X,d)$ contains none of it's boundary points. Take some $x\in Y$ and define $$ \varepsilon=\inf_{y\in \mathrm{Bd}(Y)}d(y,x)/2. $$ We know that $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$, but since $Y$ contains none of it's boundary points, we can gaurantee $x\neq y$ and so $\varepsilon >0$. As such, if $x_0\in B(x,\varepsilon)$ then surely $x_0\in Y$, since each point in $ B(x,\varepsilon)$ is less than half the minimum required distance to exit the set $Y$. So $B(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq Y$ and hence, $Y$ is open. $\blacksquare$

Comment: What exactly is your $\varepsilon_0$? From the way you phrase it, it feels like you are trying to imply that $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ is such that $B(y, \varepsilon_0) \subset Y$ for all $y \in Y$. That is certainly not true for an arbitrary open $Y$.

Comment: Even in your definition of $\varepsilon$ for the second part: Note that the infimum of a set consisting of positive reals can be $0$. So your reasoning for $\varepsilon > 0$ does not hold.

Comment: Would I rectify the problem if I changed the infimum to a minimum? Then surely $\varepsilon >0$, right?

Comment: For your first comment: from my understanding, aren't I garaunteed some $\varepsilon_0>0$ by the definition of an open set? That of which being, you can construct an open ball that remains in the set for any point?

Comment: But then, an infinite set need not have a minimum. So you would have to justify why minimum actually exists.

Comment: The definition of open set guarantees that for every $y \in Y$, there exists some $\varepsilon_y > 0$ such that $B(y, \varepsilon_y) \subset Y$. I am now explicitly putting the subscript to indicate that $\varepsilon$ can depend on $y$. There is no guarantee that you can find a "universal" $\varepsilon$. For a simple example, consider $Y := (0, 1) \subset \Bbb R$. This is an open subset but you can't find any $\varepsilon$ that works for all $y \in Y$.

Comment: For your first comment: it seems intuitive that a minimum should exist, however I'm unsure how I'd prove that it ought to. Is it a dead end trying to prove this and should I go about it another way?
For your second comment: I'm unsure where I said that $\varepsilon_0$ holds for every $y$. This is why I made it distinct from $\varepsilon$ which was used on the previous sentence. I thought it went without saying that $\varepsilon_0$ depended on $g$. Should I make this more explicit in my proof? Or have I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Bd}{Bd}$Open $\Rightarrow$ Does not contain any boundary point:
Your proof is correct. As mentioned in the comments, I would just phrase it a bit differently. I would write

> Suppose $g \in Y \cap \Bd Y$. Then, there exists $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that $B(g ,\varepsilon_0) \subset Y$...

The difference is simply that I write $g$ first and then $\varepsilon_0$, which makes it clear that I'm allowing $\varepsilon_0$ to depend on $g$.

---

Open $\Leftarrow$ Does not contain any boundary point:

Here, there is a graver problem since the $\inf$ of a set consisting of positive reals can be $0$. However, it is not so grave because of the following fact.

> Fact: Let $K \subset X$ be a nonempty closed set and suppose that $x \notin K$. Then $$\inf_{y \in K} d(x, y) > 0.$$

Firstly, note that this solves your problem since $\Bd Y := \overline{Y} \cap \overline{Y^c}$ is indeed closed.

> To prove the fact, simply note that if the $\inf$ is $0$, then for every $n \ge 1$, we can find $y_n \in K$ such that $d(x, y_n) < 1/n$. But this means that $y_n \to x$. Since $K$ is closed, it would follow that $x \in K$, a contradiction.

However, I still have an issue with how you are concluding it afterwards. You write "then surely $x_0 \in Y$, since each point in $B(x, \varepsilon)$ is less than half the minimum required distance to exit the set $Y$." Depending on what stage you are at, you might want to be more formal and not state it like that. (Here it seems that you are using some sort of intuitive idea of boundary.)

I would go for a different approach by contrapositive.

> Suppose $y \in Y$ is *not* an interior point. Then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $B(y, \varepsilon) \cap Y^c \neq \varnothing$.
> Thus, $y \in \overline{Y^c}$. Since $y \in Y \subset \overline{Y}$ to begin with, we get that $y \in \overline{Y} \cap \overline{Y^c} = \Bd Y$.
> This means that $Y$ contains a boundary point.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you!